# trace execution path of python interpreter

Tags: python, debugging, trace

The following works nice to see what the interpreter does:

```
python -m trace --ignore-dir=$HOME/lib64:$HOME/lib:/usr -t path-to/script.py
```

But there are too many lines. I would like to hide the lines which happen during importing a file.

Example: I am not interested in lines like this:

```
saved_filter.py(9): class SavedFilter(models.Model):
saved_filter.py(10):     name = models.TextField(max_length=256)
saved_filter.py(11):     user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, blank=True)
```

I could not find a solution in the docs:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html

**Update**
If there is a different way to get the result, for example a different python package (not trace), this would be a good solution, too.

**Update 2**
The tracing should be non-interactive.

**Update 3**

I tried the solution provided by Martin v. Löwis. It works in some cases, but not all.

file foo.py

```
import bar

def main():
    f=bar.Foo()
    f.my_func()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

file bar.py

```
class Foo(object):
    def my_func(self):
        def inner():
            print('#in inner')
            return 'inner'
        print('#in my_func()')
        inner()
        return 1
```

If I call foo.py, the wanted result looks similar to this:

foo.py: f=bar.Foo()
foo.py: f.my_func()
bar.py: print('#in my_func()')
bar.py: inner()
bar.py: print('#in inner')
bar.py: return 'inner'
bar.py: return 1

Result of trace2.py

```
> python tmp/trace2-orig.py --trace tmp/foo.py 
 --- modulename: foo, funcname: <module>
 --- modulename: bar, funcname: <module>
 --- modulename: bar, funcname: Foo
bar.py(1): class Foo(object):               <======= Import lines
bar.py(2):     def my_func(self):
 --- modulename: foo, funcname: main
foo.py(4):     f=bar.Foo()
foo.py(5):     f.my_func()
 --- modulename: bar, funcname: my_func
bar.py(3):         def inner():
bar.py(6):         print('#in my_func()')
#in my_func()
bar.py(7):         inner()
 --- modulename: bar, funcname: inner
bar.py(4):             print('#in inner')
#in inner
bar.py(5):             return 'inner'
bar.py(8):         return 1
 --- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(80):         sys.settrace(None)
```

Unfortunately there is still `class Foo(object)` which is something executed during import.

I guess the detection of code loading and executing does not cover all cases.

Comment: Try to collect info by [Trace object method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html#trace.Trace.runctx) call inside your script to collect info about your target function and print given [CoverageResults](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html#trace.CoverageResults) aftert hat.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a script trace2.py as

```
import trace

OrigTrace = trace.Trace
class Trace2(trace.Trace):
    def localtrace_trace(self, frame, why, arg):
        if why == "line" and frame.f_code.co_name == '<module>':
            return self.localtrace
        return OrigTrace.localtrace_trace(self, frame, why, arg)

trace.Trace=Trace2
trace.main()
```

and run `python -m trace2 -t script.py` you will not see trace output from lines that are on the module level.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your solution. It does not catch all cases of code loading yet. See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pdb library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html), by this library you can make breakpoint and/or inject python statements to the break point line by interactive console UI and doing more other actions.
;)

Comment: I updated the question: The tracing should be non-interactive. AFAIK pdb is made for interactive debugging. Please tell me, if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide code paths during import, just pipe it through a filter like this one:

```
import re
import sys

cur = None
skip_re = re.compile(r'^(?P<filename>.+)?\((\d*)\):\s*import')
for line in sys.stdin:
    if cur and not line.startswith(cur):
        continue
    cur = None
    match = skip_re.match(line)
    if match:
        cur = match.group('filename')
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```